# TinyMCE used in a partial is not loading when it is called in another partial remotely

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, renderpartial

In my rails app, I have a page for creating a new question. Also I need to create the same type of sub question under the parent question. So the layout being the same, I have used  a partial `_new.html.erb`(which holds layouts for creating different types of questions). Then for adding the question text, I have used another partial(`_add_questiontext.html.erb`) containg a text area and there I have integrated the `TinyMCE` editor properly. When I am calling the '`_add_questiontext`' partial from '`_new.html.erb`'. and since `_new.html.erb` is being loaded remotely using new.js.erb with the follwoing contents,

```
$("#sub_question").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "new")) %>");
```

when loaded, the text area for the parent question is shown with TinyMCE editor, but sub question textarea is not. What could be the reason?

![Question creating template][1]

Please help :)-

Comment: do you have an accessible live example?